# How to declare a pointer to an user defined object with constructor?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers

I have two classes: **Game** and **inputs**.
Game class has a constructor that takes no variables, while inputs class takes pointer to Game object as an argument (or at least is supposed to).

In main I create two instances of thes objects:

```
Game main_game; 
inputs main_inputs(&main_game);
```

And that is the troublesome part of inputs.h:

```
class inputs{
public:
   Game *wsk;
   inputs(Game *);
};
```

The compiler gives me two errors in inputs.h:

1) 'Game' does not name a type
2) expected ')' before '*' token

What am I doing wrong, trying to pass adress of Game object to inputs constructor?

Comment: You have to `#include` the header with the definition of `Game` or provide a forward-declaration and do that in the .cpp file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you forgot to forward declare `Game`:

```
class Game;

class inputs{
public:
   Game *wsk;
   inputs(Game *);
};
```

Comment: What do you not understand about "'Game' does not name a type"?